# i18n using AOT in Angular 4

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular2-aot

We have a requirement and asked to use Angular 4 and I am working on implementing internationalization. Since I am new to angular I was going through i18n and found that i18n with AOT currently supports only the translation in template.
What does it mean when they say the support is only in the template, can anybody explain with some example.

Are there any good examples to implement i18n and also to render based on browser locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you cannot translate text from within your TypeScript code; only static HTML content can be translated.

#### Can be translated

```html
<p i18n>Text in a paragraph</p>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<my-component title="My Title" i18n-title></my-component>
                     ^^^^^^^
```

#### Cannot be translated

```js
if (hasError) {
  showErrorMessage('An error has occured');
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

If you want to translate message from within your code, you have to either implement some kind of `I18nService` yourself, or use one of the alternative libraries like [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

For more in-depth information, just stick to the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n).

Comment: can I have both ngx-translate and i18n in my application? For the template, i will go with i18n and front-end validations use a library like ngx-translate. Backend validations can be handled by server based on the language sent.

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem, besides having two different systems to maintain at the same time. I haven't tried it myself though.